# Selenium: pressing enter on popup before the website stops loading

Tags: selenium

we have begun to automate our SAP system using selenium (on chrome). In the beginning, when we enter the link, it starts loading, and before it finishes loading, a windows popup appears. We have to press enter to make it disappear. Only then the page finishes loading and we can continue. The problem is, that when we write driver.get(Path), and after that another line of code, the second line of code is executed only after the page finishes loading. And the enter is supposed to be pressed before that. Does anyone know what to do?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This site is to help you with coding problems, and the usual approach is for you to share your code and explain what you have tried. Learn more here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is selenium's [Page Load Strategy](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/page_loading_strategy)

The default is `normal` and, as you observe:

> This will make Selenium WebDriver to wait for the entire page is loaded

It sounds like you want `none` AND in combination with [explicit waits](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/waits/#explicit-wait)

> When set to none Selenium WebDriver only waits until the initial page is downloaded.

This is the page load strategy in...

java:

```java
        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        chromeOptions.setPageLoadStrategy(PageLoadStrategy.NONE);
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

c#

```cs
      var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
      chromeOptions.PageLoadStrategy = PageLoadStrategy.None;
      IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

python:

```py
options = Options()
options.page_load_strategy = 'none'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

Be sure to include the the explicit `webdrvierwait` on your popup to ensure it is ready before trying to interact with it or you will get `NoSuchElementExcption`s.